# Delete files with broken file name

Tags: windows, filesystems, file-management

I was using NodeJSPortable on a PortableApps flash drive that was plugged into a computer I didn't have administrative access to. I tried running `npm install socket.io` not only did it not work but it changed the file names in one of the node.js directories to invalid file names so that I can't even delete them. The file names are using characters I've never even seen before and I can't rename them because the file "doesn't exist"  how do I delete files no matter what the name is? I can't delete them from the file explorer. I tried a Linux mint and a Windows 7 and 8 to delete the files none of them worked. The PortableApps platform is built for Windows. 
[image: picture of the files]

Comment: What operating system? Please [edit] your question and add the correct tags for your OS.

Comment: I tried both a Linux mint  and a Windows 7 and 8 to delete the files neither worked. The PortableApps platform is designed for Windows.

Comment: Please give some example filenames.

Comment: I can't. They are alt key characters or something like that. Not supported by what I'm using for stack exchange

Comment: You should at least be able to provide a screenshot. Upload your image to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get a link you can share. [Edit] your question to include this link and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image for you.

Comment: Okay I'll do that next time I'm able.

Comment: What about reformatting the flash drive. Of course if you don't need the files.

Comment: i have other files on there that i need. its a 64 GB flash drive with about 30 GB full id rather not reformat it.

Comment: this link http://serverfault.com/questions/95581/delete-file-containing-invalid-characters-in-windows  suggests chkdsk  - could do chkdsk /f (or I suppose /r since /r implies /f).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [windows PE](http://bit.ly/1drv-win10pex86), because in there, no permission.

Comment: it isnt a question of permissions it is a question of the file system being able to access the file itself. since the file system only recognizes standard characters it cant find the file in order to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to delete the files this way:

1. Determine what file system code page has the other computer. (For details, see the link below.)
2. Switch your computer to that code page.
3. Now all the file names should appear correct and all file operations including deletion should be possible.
4. Switch the code page back to your original one.

I recently wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43267895/2392157) at the StackOverflow to cover some details of this situation.

Of course, in some cases there could be easier way: simply reformat your flash drive. :)

**How to avoid the problem:**
Do not let filenames with national Unicode characters go plain to non-NTFS drive. If you need them there, zip them.